# What is the correct primary accent in the word "andavamo"?

Tags: single-words

Which of these two are correct? Or do they have different meanings?

1. And**a**vamo
2. Andav**a**mo

I bolded the letter which is stressed in each.

Comment: Andàvamo is not an Italian word. Andavàmo is. Editing the title for clarity.

Answer (score 4):

1 Andav**a**mo (*we were going*) is correct. The primary accent sits in the penultimate sillable, which makes it a *piana* word.

2  And**a**vamo is not a correct word; you are likely confusing it with and**a**vano (note the `n`; it means *they were going*).

Answer (score 3):

In the interest of having a correct answer to the question, the correct stress is *andavàmo* (so with the stress on the penultimate syllable). This can be checked in any conjugation table, for example at page 286 of Serianni's grammar book (note that the verb *andare* is regular at the imperfect tense, with root *and-*).